# Why is my memory not being fully utilized on my laptop?

Tags: memory, windows-10, video, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

Got a Toshiba Satellite C75D-B7202, which came with a pretty modest 6GB RAM.  But it's absolutely *crawling*, approaching the speed of a glacier at times.

Checked out performance in Task Manager:

[image]

Huh?  Wassup with the 3.5 GB?

Checked out Speccy:

[image]

I don't get it.  I have 4GB + 2GB, but the computer is performing as if it only has 3.5 GB!  What is going on here?

Comment: You have a 64-bit version of Windows installed?  I realize after looking at the screenshot some more, its a stupid question considering, you have 2.5GB reversed by hardware.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the RAM being shared between the system and the Video card. The full specs for your system are at http://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/satellite/c70/C75D-B7202 and if you click the star next to RAM you will see an explanation of this. You would have to go into the BIOS to change the amount of RAM given to the onboard AMD video card.

[image]

Comment: So how much is the minimum RAM I should allocate to the video card in the BIOS?  It's being used only as a work computer; no hectic gaming requirements.

Comment: From your screen cap I would presume your windows 8.1 or windows 10 so I would not recommend going under 1 GB. Microsoft does not have a hard number in the minim specs but does list "DirectX 9 or later with WDDM 1.0 driver" which can go as low as 256MB of Video RAM. You can always set it to something low, boot to windows and if the video performance is too poor/suffers to much reboot and bump it up to the next amount in your options list.

Comment: I'd just go to 256 MiB for work use.  I've got Win10 machines at work with discrete cards of just 256 MiB and they're fine.  I'd rather have the RAM for normal uses (including cache) than video when not gaming.

Comment: Hmm, just got into the BIOS (now called UEFI) and there doesn't appear to be anywhere to set the RAM allocated to the video card.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You might not be able to adjust it, I have seen that in more locked down systems. As I don't own the model laptop you have my only suggestion is to read the manual or if it is still under support give them a call.